# Are there purely imaginary roots of an irreducible whose exponents are mixed parity and gcd of 1?

Tags: roots, irreducible-polynomials

I am interested in counting the purely imaginary roots of $P(x)$ which has integer coefficients and $P(x) \ne 0$.

I consider 3 cases:

1. The powers of $x$ in the terms of $P$ are odd. The imaginary roots of $P(x)$ correspond to the real roots of $P(ix)$. But since all powers of $x$ are odd, the $i$ will appear in every term except the constant term, $c$, to give $c + iS(x)$. This is real when $S(x)=0$...but it can never be zero. So if the powers are all odd there are no purely imaginary roots.
2. When the powers share a common divisor, $d$, let $R(x^d) = P(x)$. Counting the number of imaginary roots reduces to two cases:
   a. if $d$ is even, count the positive (or negative) roots of $R(x)$ when $d/2$ is even (or odd) and multiplying by 2. Example: for $x^4 + 10x^2 + 1$, $d=2$ and there are 4 imaginary roots, two each for the negative roots of $x^2 + 10x + 1$.
   b. if $d$ is odd, there will be an imaginary root for $P(x)$ for each imaginary root of $R(x)$. Example: for $x^12 + 10x^6 + 1$, $d=3$ and there are 4 imaginary roots, each corresponding (though not equal) to the imaginary roots of $R(x) = x^4 + 10*x^2 + 1$
3. When the exponents are mixed (even and odd), and share no common divisor, then let $P(ix) = E(x) + x^m i e(x)$ where $E(x)$ has all even powers of $P$ (including the constant term) and $m$ is the smallest odd exponent in $P$, e.g. for $P(x) = x^5 + 2x^4 + x^3 - 1$, $E(x) = 2x^4 - 1$, $m = 3$ and $e(x) = x^2 - 1$. The real roots of $P(ix)$ are the real roots in common between $E(x)$ and $x^me(x)$. Since $E(x)$ includes the constant term, $E(0) \ne 0$ so the $x^m$ can be disregarded. So whether or not $P(x)$ has imaginary roots depends on whether or not $E(x)$ and $e(x)$ will share any real roots in common. In general, yes. For example, using the expression from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596214/prove-the-roots-of-a-complex-polynomial-are-imaginary) we have $P(x) = x^5 - 6x^4 + 15x^3 - 34x^2 + 36x - 48$ from which we identify $E(x) = -6x^4 + 34x^2 - 48$ and $e(x) = x^4 - 15x^2 + 36$ which share the common roots of $x^2 = 3$. But this would have been evident if the expression had been factored at the outset to show that $x^2 + 3$ was a factor giving rise to two imaginary roots.

The **question** I have continues from (3) by adding the constraint that $P(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. **Will irreducible $P(x)$ (in which the $gcd$ of the powers of $x$ is 1 and both even and odd exponents are present) have any imaginary roots** or, equivalently, will $E(x)$ and $e(x)$ share any real roots in common?

Note: although we know that two irreducibles share [no roots in common](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996785/irreducible-polynomials-with-same-root), $E(x)$ and $e(x)$ might no longer be irreducible as demonstrated by the first irreducible expression given in (3) which produced $E(x) = 2x^4 - 1$ and $e(x) = x^2 - 1$ (which, though they have real roots, have no common real factor so there are no purely imaginary roots for $x^5 + 2x^4 + x^3 - 1$.)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a full algorithm to determine the existence of pure imaginary roots.

1. Write $P(ix)=E(x) + ie(x)$, with $E,e$ with real coefficients.
2. Compute $Q=gcd(E,e)$ using [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Polynomials).
3. Determine the number of real roots of Q using [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem)

The number obtained in step 3 is the number of pure imaginary roots of $P$.

---

You asked if there are irreducible polynomials (I assume over $\mathbb{Q}$) with pure imaginary roots.

Yes, many $P(x)= x^2+a$ for $a$ a non-square in $\mathbb{Q}$.

---

If $ia$ is algebraic then its minimal polynomial is of the form $\prod_k(x^2+a_k)$, where $a_k$ are the conjugates of $a^2$. Therefore, all terms of $P$ have even degree.

Comment: I understand that I have an algorithm and I know that it works but my question is whether we would ever expect to find roots in common for $E(x)$ and $e(x)$ that come from an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ that have powers of x with no common factor in exponents and mixed parity. The example you give of $x^2 + a$ does not satisfy those criteria. Note, also, that the $e(x)$ that you defined is not the same as the one I defined (but I understand that it works for the algorithm that you describe).

Comment: The question I ask comes from an extension of case 3 and I have edited the question to make the scope more clear. The question does not concern the algorithm but whether or not we would ever expect to find imaginary roots for such an irreducible polynomial.

Comment: @smichr If $ia$ is algebraic, then its minimal polynomial is $\prod_k(x^2+a_k)$, where $a_k$ are the conjugates of $a^2$. Therefore, all the powers of $P$ are even.

Comment: I think that is the insight that I am looking for. So imaginary roots will only come from factors that have only even powers. I accepted the modified answer.